# work experience arises from teaching

Tags: word-choice

I am going to make up a sentence.

(ex) Most of John's work experience **arises** from teaching high school students.

Does the word arises fit my sentence?

Comment: You could use '***comes***' also.

Answer (score 1):

'Arose' is the past tense of arise.

'Most of John's work experience *arose* from teaching high school students.'

Answer (score 1):

**Stems** from, which [means the same](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stem%20from) as Varun KN suggestion, **comes** from.

But it occurred to me that there is another point here.  You could say that John's expertise was gained from teaching high school students.  But teaching high school students was actually his work experience; his experience didn't arise from it.  So you could simply say, "John's work experience was teaching high school students."

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "arises" and "stems" are both OK in this sentence, but maybe "comes" sounds the most natural. You could also say, "Most of John's work experience is from teaching high school students."